# Format date and Value

Tags: excel, date, datetime, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have a synchronized List from SharePoint in Excel with Date, Names and  sold items to sume.

The Date appears as Datetime(2017-01-01 13:00:00).
In order to do a Pivot Table I wanted to Format it so only appears the month and the year. (January 17).

The Problem is, although the Date is in Month-Year Format, when I do the Pivot table it seems to get the original values of the date, so it doesn´t recognize "January 17" as a Month and it repeats the field several times because it still recognize it as a DateTime value and I can´t get the sold items of one month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a column to convert the format `2017-01-01 13:00:00` to `January-17`

If the datetime is in cell `A1` use the formula below,

`=TEXT(A1,"mmmm-yy")`